# Accessing local's codeigniter project from mobile browser gives 404 Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have codeigniter project in localhost and I want to access it by my mobile browser. I have set my mobile and PC in same network, so I can access the local from my mobile by typing its IP address. I can access everything on htdocs, but when I was accessing codeigniter project, it gives me 404 not found on mobile browser, but there is no problem when I access it in PC browser by typing `ip-address/codeigniter-project`.

My base_url is `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_name/';`

My .htaccess

`Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

I am not sure what I have to do, but it may be something I should change in .htaccess or other config. Any clue?

Comment: have you checked for firewall?? Disable firewall and check once. It may be the reason.

Comment: Yes, I've disabled my firewall and check it again. No result. I think there are configs that I should change, since I can access all my htdocs folder, except this codeigniter project.

Comment: what is your base url in config?? Please update the question with it.

Comment: @kishor10d updated

Comment: make it blank and then check. Or instead of localhost - enter your machine ip.

Comment: both scenarios give no difference in mobile, but I still can access it by desktop with `ip-address/project_name`

Comment: do you have .htaccess file?, please update that code.

Comment: @kishor10d Sure. Updated.

Comment: ```DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]```

Check with this.

Comment: What OS you are using?

Comment: @Tpojka Windows

Comment: Is it set hosts file with loopback for certain IP already?

Comment: @Tpojka fixed by changing CI config file. kishor10d suggestions leads me to fix it.

Comment: Good. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by changing base_url in config to ip-address/project-name

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://10.0.0.2/project_name/';
```

instead of

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_name/';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case my local area network address is 10.0.0.2. This is the ip which you need to access your localhost on your android phone over wifi. To test it is working type this ip address in your desktop browser where your localhost server is installed.

Comment: Everything works fine, but it is not worked in my codeigniter project. I've acessed both desktop and mobile by ip address and I can access some folders in my htdocs. Other projects using native php can be accessed.